# Jenkins/Groovy: How to call withCredentials() from a class constructor?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, runtime-error, credentials

**How do I call `withCredentials()` from a Groovy class constructor?**

Why does this:

```
@Library('my-sandbox-libs@dev') sandbox_lib

pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage( "1" ) {
      steps {
        script {
          try {
            def my_obj = new org.obj.Obj()
          }
          catch(Exception e) {
            echo "Jenkinsfile: ${e.toString()}"
            throw e
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
// src/org/obj/Obj.groovy
package org.obj

public class Obj {
  def secret_
  Obj() {
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'test_secret_text', variable: 'val')]) {
      this.secret_ = val
    }
  }
}
```

...generate this error:

```
Jenkinsfile: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.obj.Obj.string() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[credentialsId:test_secret_text, variable:val]]
Possible solutions: toString(), toString(), print(java.io.PrintWriter), print(java.lang.Object), find(), split(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

### ?

**Update:**
Tried the following, in line with @daggett's answer:

```
// src/org/obj/Obj.groovy
package org.obj

public class Obj {
  def secret_
  Obj(pipeline) {
    pipeline.withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'test_secret_text',
                                     variable: 'val')]) {
      this.secret_ = val
    }
  }
}
```

```
@Library('my-sandbox-libs@dev') sandbox_lib

pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage( "1" ) {
      steps {
        script { def my_obj = new org.obj.Obj(this) }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...which generated the error `Posting build status of FAILED to bitbucket.company.comhudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.obj.Obj.string() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[credentialsId:test_secret_text, variable:val]] Possible solutions: toString(), toString(), print(java.io.PrintWriter), print(java.lang.Object), find(), split(groovy.lang.Closure)`

However, the following -- just an experiment -- runs fine:

```
// src/org/obj/Obj.groovy
package org.obj

public class Obj {
  def secret_
  Obj(pipeline) {
    pipeline.echo "hello world"
  }
}
```

Note: I also tried `public class Obj implements Serializable {...}`, which did not change the noted error.

I'm still having a hard time building a mental model of the Jenkins/Groovy language, but to me this appears as though there's something "special" about `withCredentials()` preventing it from being called from a class constructor.

In case it's relevant, I have Jenkins version 2.190.3, which has Groovy version 2.4.12.

Comment: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#accessing-steps

Answer (score 0):

this should help: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#accessing-steps

the easiest way - to pass pipeline as argument into constructor

```
public class Obj {
  def secret_
  Obj(pipeline) {
     pipeline.withCredentials(...
  }
```

and call it like this

```
...
 steps {
        script {
            def my_obj = new org.obj.Obj(this)
```

Comment: This looked so promising, and would have been a perfect solution, but it failed with error `No signature of method: org.obj.Obj.string() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[credentialsId:test_secret_text, variable:val]]` which I don't understand what is trying to be communicated. Note that I did also try `public class Obj implements Serializable {`, which did not change the error. I hope you recognize the error/solution, because there's obviously something quite fundamental about Jenkins/Groovy I'm quite not comprehending. I updated my post accordingly.

Comment: right. that's a tricky part - i don't have jenkins in hands and can't test. `string` (in lowercase) is not a standard java/groovy method. so i would try `pipeline.string(...` or a `$class` binding syntax: `[  [$class: 'StringBinding',  credentialsId:...`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing the following:

Create a file in /vars which will do the `withCredential`.
File name for example: `/vars/dockerCommands.groovy`
(I called it `docker.groovy` before, but docker is an existing step already, so I advise to change it so it will not conflict.)

```
.
.
.
def login(String cred, String reg) {
  withCredentials([
    usernamePassword(credentialsId: cred ,usernameVariable: 'DOCKER_USER', passwordVariable: 'DOCKER_PASSWORD')
    ]){
      docker login -u ${DOCKER_USER} -p ${DOCKER_PASSWORD} ${reg}" 
  }
}
.
.
```

In the class I called for this step.

```
.
.
public void login(String cred, String reg) {
  this.steps.dockerCommands.login(cred, reg)
}
.
.
```

Note, steps is a private var which is equivalent to your `pipeline` var.
I create it in the constructor method of the class.